# Basic Spring based WSSecurity client gets a null response

Tags: java, spring, ws-security

I've been following [this tutorial](https://memorynotfound.com/spring-ws-certificate-authentication-wss4j/) to learn how to develop a basic spring client and server application using wssecurity (certificates).
The demo works beautifully, but i need to deploy my application on a wildfly server, so i had to change the example a bit in order to avoid the embedded tomcat, the changes are as follows:

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.memorynotfound.spring.ws</groupId>
<artifactId>ws-security-certificate-wss4j-security-interceptor</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>SPRING-WS - ${project.artifactId}</name>
<url>http://memorynotfound.com</url>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
     </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
     <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>         
     <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>xjc</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <sources>
                    <source>src/main/resources/xsd</source>
                </sources>
                <generatePackage>com.memorynotfound.beer</generatePackage>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>


</build>
```

RunServer.java

```
package com.memorynotfound.server;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class RunServer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(RunServer.class);
}

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(applicationClass);
}

private static Class<RunServer> applicationClass = RunServer.class;

}
```

BeerEndpoint.java

```
package it.corvallis.soap.endpoint;

import com.memorynotfound.beer.Beer;
import com.memorynotfound.beer.GetBeerRequest;
import com.memorynotfound.beer.GetBeerResponse;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.PayloadRoot;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.RequestPayload;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.ResponsePayload;
import org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.annotation.SoapAction;

@Endpoint
public class BeerEndpoint {

public static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://memorynotfound.com/beer";

@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "getBeerRequest")
@SoapAction("http://localhost:8080/ws/beers")
@ResponsePayload
public GetBeerResponse getBeer(@RequestPayload GetBeerRequest request)  {
    GetBeerResponse beerResponse = new GetBeerResponse();
    Beer beer = new Beer();
    beer.setId(request.getId());
    beer.setName("Beer name");
    beerResponse.setBeer(beer);
    return beerResponse;
}

}
```

I deployed the server application on my wildfly and i tried to call it using the same client application used in the tutorial. The service seems to answer correctly, the beerResponse object is correctly istantiated, but, as soon as the object is being sent back to the the client, i see it's NULL.

What am i missing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Oh well, next time i'll read better. At the same link of my first post, a guy asked the same question in the comments, here is the solution: add a callBackHandler to the client configuration, and modify the securityInterceptor to use this handler.

SoapClientConfig.java

```
package com.memorynotfound.client;

import org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerFactoryCustomizer;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.ws.client.support.interceptor.ClientInterceptor;
import org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j2.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor;
import org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j2.callback.KeyStoreCallbackHandler;
import org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j2.support.CryptoFactoryBean;

import java.io.IOException;

@Configuration
public class SoapClientConfig {


@Bean
public Wss4jSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor() throws Exception {
    Wss4jSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor = new Wss4jSecurityInterceptor();

    // set security actions
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementActions("Timestamp Signature Encrypt");

    // sign the request
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementUsername("client");
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementPassword("changeit");
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementSignatureCrypto(getCryptoFactoryBean().getObject());

    // encrypt the request
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementEncryptionUser("server-public");
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementEncryptionCrypto(getCryptoFactoryBean().getObject());
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementEncryptionParts("{Content}{http://memorynotfound.com/beer}getBeerRequest");

 // sign the response
    securityInterceptor.setValidationActions("Signature Encrypt");
    securityInterceptor.setValidationSignatureCrypto(getCryptoFactoryBean().getObject());
    securityInterceptor.setValidationDecryptionCrypto(getCryptoFactoryBean().getObject());
    securityInterceptor.setValidationCallbackHandler(securityCallbackHandler());

    return securityInterceptor;
}

@Bean
public CryptoFactoryBean getCryptoFactoryBean() throws IOException {
    CryptoFactoryBean cryptoFactoryBean = new CryptoFactoryBean();
    cryptoFactoryBean.setKeyStorePassword("changeit");
    cryptoFactoryBean.setKeyStoreLocation(new ClassPathResource("client.jks"));
    return cryptoFactoryBean;
}

@Bean
public Jaxb2Marshaller getMarshaller(){
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    marshaller.setContextPath("com.memorynotfound.beer");
    return marshaller;
}

@Bean
public BeerClient getBeerClient() throws Exception {
    BeerClient beerClient = new BeerClient();
    beerClient.setMarshaller(getMarshaller());
    beerClient.setUnmarshaller(getMarshaller());
    beerClient.setDefaultUri("http://localhost:8080/ws/beers");
    ClientInterceptor[] interceptors = new ClientInterceptor[]{securityInterceptor()};
    beerClient.setInterceptors(interceptors);
    return beerClient;
}

@Bean
public KeyStoreCallbackHandler securityCallbackHandler(){
KeyStoreCallbackHandler callbackHandler = new KeyStoreCallbackHandler();
callbackHandler.setPrivateKeyPassword("changeit");
return callbackHandler;
}

}
```